# How to improve speed of MPI I/O on large number of cores?

Tags: fortran90, hpc, mpi-io

I've been trying to run a code using MPI I/O on a large number of cores. The time required for each core to read from and write to a single file (the same for all cores) increases with the number of cores used. I'm currently using 512 cores and this problem is making my project unfeasible. The problem appears, however, even when running on 8 cores; it then takes about 0.2 seconds to read the first real number in the file. On 32 cores it takes more then 30 seconds to write one real number. I'm running it here: https://www.msi.umn.edu/hpc/itasca. The following simple code generates exactly this problem (the counting of the number of elements in the file might seem unnecessary here but it is necessary in my actual code):

```
PROGRAM MAIN

USE MPI
IMPLICIT NONE

! INITIALIZING VARIABLES   

REAL(8) :: A, B
INTEGER :: COUNT_IO, i, j, ST, GO, tag, t, nb_bytes, N, d_each, d_start, d_end, NN
REAL(8) :: time_start, time_end

! VARIABLES RELATED TO MPI

INTEGER :: ierror  ! returns error messages from the mpi subroutines 
INTEGER :: rank    ! identification number of each processor
INTEGER :: nproc   ! number of processors
INTEGER, DIMENSION(mpi_status_size):: status
INTEGER(kind= MPI_OFFSET_KIND ) :: offset
INTEGER :: fh  ! file handle

! EXECUTABLE

    ! INITIALIZE THE MPI ENVIRONMENT

    CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)                           ! initialize MPI 
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierror)  ! obtain rank for each node
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nproc,ierror) ! obtain the number of nodes
    CALL MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_REAL8,nb_bytes,ierror)

    CALL MPI_FILE_OPEN (MPI_COMM_WORLD,"file.dat",MPI_MODE_RDWR+MPI_MODE_UNIQUE_OPEN,MPI_INFO_NULL,fh,ierror)    

    NN = 2048

    DO d_each=1,NN
        IF (d_each*nproc>=NN) EXIT
    END DO
    d_start = rank*d_each+1 
    d_end   = MIN((rank+1)*d_each,NN)

    DO t = d_start,d_end

        ! READING ONE THREAD AT A TIME

        tag = 1

        GO = 0

        IF (rank .gt. 0) THEN
            CALL MPI_RECV (GO,1,MPI_INTEGER,rank-1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,status,ierror)
        ENDIF

        time_start = MPI_WTIME()

        i  = 0
        ST = 0
        COUNT_IO = 0

        DO WHILE ((i .lt. 100000) .AND. (ST .eq. 0))
            i = i+1
            offset = nb_bytes*(i-1)
            CALL MPI_FILE_READ_AT (fh,offset,A,1,MPI_REAL8,status,ierror)
            IF (status(1) .eq. 0) THEN
                COUNT_IO = i
                ST = 1
            ELSE
                COUNT_IO = 0
            END IF        
        ENDDO

        N = (COUNT_IO - 1)

        IF (N .gt. 0) THEN

            offset = 0                      
            CALL MPI_FILE_READ_AT (fh,offset,B,1,MPI_REAL8,status,ierror)

        ENDIF

        time_end = MPI_WTIME()

        PRINT *, 'My rank is', rank, 'Time for read  =',time_end-time_start 

        GO = 1    
        IF (rank .lt. nproc-1) THEN
            CALL MPI_SEND (GO,1, MPI_INTEGER ,rank+1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,ierror)
        ENDIF

        CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

        ! WRITING ONE THREAD AT A TIME

        tag = 2

        GO = 0

        IF (rank .gt. 0) THEN
            CALL MPI_RECV (GO,1,MPI_INTEGER,rank-1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,status,ierror)
        ENDIF

        time_start = MPI_WTIME()

        i  = 0
        ST = 0
        COUNT_IO = 0

        DO WHILE ((i .lt. 100000) .AND. (ST .eq. 0))
            i = i+1
            offset = nb_bytes*(i-1)
            CALL MPI_FILE_READ_AT (fh,offset,A,1,MPI_REAL8,status,ierror)
            IF (status(1) .eq. 0) THEN
                COUNT_IO = i
                ST = 1
            ELSE
                COUNT_IO = 0
            END IF        
        ENDDO

        N = (COUNT_IO - 1)

        offset = nb_bytes*N
        CALL MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT (fh,offset,0.0D0,1,MPI_REAL8,status,ierror) 

        time_end = MPI_WTIME()  

        PRINT *, 'My rank is', rank, 'Time for write =',time_end-time_start

        GO = 1    
        IF (rank .lt. nproc-1) THEN
            CALL MPI_SEND (GO,1, MPI_INTEGER ,rank+1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD ,ierror)
        ENDIF

        CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)

    ENDDO

    CALL MPI_FILE_CLOSE (fh,ierror)

    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)

END PROGRAM MAIN
```

Comment: Wow.  If you have 32 processes working on a ~128MB file, I count something like 64 billion fseeks and 64 billion 8-byte reads/writes, each of which are I/O operations which take real time, ignoring the two barriers and 2048 send/receive pairs.  All the reads are sequential, but doing the seeks from multiple processes in parallel on the same file pretty much guarantees your file system/disk cache can't take advantage of that.  I would imagine even at 2 processes this would grind to a halt.  Could you please outline in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: From the system description, it appears that the main file system is NFS which in general has extremely poor performance. Even if you use the Lustre filesystem, it won't work well with small files (128 MB is a small file!). And in general, as Jonathan Dursi has already pointed out, reading one floating-point number at a time with MPI I/O results in extremely pool performance.

Comment: First thank you both for the quick response. I'm definitely not an expert on mpi-io and could really use some advice. Here is what I am trying to do in words: I'm trying to maximize a function which takes about 10 minutes to evaluate and my optimization routine requires a large number of evaluations. In order to speed up the evaluations I build a library of initial conditions, a single dat file. I would like each core to be able to read from (before the evaluation) and write to (after) this file. If you have any suggestion on how to do this efficiently I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user3553449 , what is the I/O pattern you're trying to set up here?  As far as I can tell, you have every process reading the same data 8 bytes at a time repeatedly, then having a barrier and doing the same thing again with a write at the end.  If you can describe the I/O pattern you're trying to implement, we can suggest alternative ways of doing that.  You're going to want to read in as much data as possible at once, process it in memory (rather than going to the file system for every double), and coordinate among processes.

Comment: @JonathanDursi, before each evaluation I need each core to know the content of the entire file (so far I have each core reading it), once the evaluation is completed I need to save the result into the file (to be used in the next evaluations). I use the counter before reading to set the size of the vector used to decide which is the best initial condition, and before writing in order to set the offset to append the file. I'm doing the writing and reading sequentially to prevent 2 cores from accessing the file simultaneously. Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to realize here is that you can read in the data in one fell swoop (or, if memory is a problem, in chunks - but it can be in much larger chunks than individual doubles!) and that you don't need to skip to the end of the file one double at a time.

Here's an example which will read in the data in arbitrary chunk sizes, processes the data as you will, and appends some data (in this case, everyone just adds 4 copies of their rank to the end of the file).  For simplicity, little python scripts help with writing and displaying test data.

```
$ ./writedata.py 
$ ./readdata.py 
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.]

$ mpirun -np 3 ./usepario
 rank:   0 got data: 0.000...   24.000 
 rank:   1 got data: 0.000...   24.000
 rank:   2 got data: 0.000...   24.000

$ ./readdata.py 
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.  14.
  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.
   1.   1.   1.   2.   2.   2.   2.]
```

usepario.f90:

```
module pario

contains
    function openFile(filename)
        use mpi
        implicit none
        integer :: openFile, ierr
        character(len=*) :: filename
        integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: off = 0

        call MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename,  &
                           ior(MPI_MODE_RDWR, MPI_MODE_UNIQUE_OPEN),  &
                           MPI_INFO_NULL, openFile, ierr)
        call MPI_File_set_view(openFile, off,  &
                               MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                               "native", MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)
    end function  openFile

    subroutine closeFile(fh)
        use mpi
        implicit none
        integer :: fh, ierr
        call MPI_File_close(fh, ierr)
    end subroutine closeFile

    function filesizedoubles(fh)
        use mpi
        implicit none
        integer :: fh, ierr
        integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: filesize, filesizedoubles
        integer :: dblsize

        call MPI_File_get_size(fh, filesize, ierr)
        call MPI_type_size(MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, dblsize, ierr)
        filesizedoubles = filesize / dblsize
    end function filesizedoubles

    subroutine getdatablock(fh, blocksize, datablock, datasize)
        use mpi
        implicit none
        integer :: fh, ierr
        integer :: blocksize, datasize
        double precision, dimension(:) :: datablock
        integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: fileloc
        integer, dimension(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: rstatus

        ! you can also experiment with read_all for non collective/synchronous file
        ! access

        call MPI_File_read(fh, datablock, blocksize, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                           rstatus, ierr)
        call MPI_Get_count(rstatus, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, datasize, ierr)
    end subroutine getdatablock

    subroutine eachappend(fh, filesize, numitems, newdata)
        use mpi
        implicit none
        integer :: fh, numitems
        integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: filesize
        double precision, dimension(:) :: newdata
        integer :: rank, ierr
        integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: offset

        call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
        offset = filesize + rank*numitems
        call MPI_File_write_at_all(fh, offset, newdata, numitems, &
                                    MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,         &
                                    MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

    end subroutine eachappend
end module pario


program usepario
    use mpi
    use pario
    implicit none

    integer :: fileh
    integer, parameter :: bufsize=1000, newsize=4
    integer(MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: filesize
    double precision, allocatable, dimension(:) :: curdata, newdata
    integer :: datasize
    integer :: rank, ierr

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

    allocate(curdata(bufsize))

    fileh = openFile("data.dat")
    filesize = filesizedoubles(fileh)

    do
        call getdatablock(fileh, bufsize, curdata, datasize)
        !! 
        !! process data here
        !!
        !! do i=1,datasize
        !!  ...dostuff...
        !! end do
        !! 
        print '(1X,A,I3,A,F8.3,A,F8.3)', 'rank: ', rank, ' got data: ', curdata(1), '...', curdata(datasize)
        if (datasize /= bufsize) exit
    end do

    deallocate(curdata)

    allocate(newdata(newsize))
    newdata = rank

    call eachappend(fileh, filesize, newsize, newdata)
    call closeFile(fileh)

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program usepario
```

writedata.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy

numdoubles = 25

data = numpy.arange(numdoubles,dtype=numpy.float64)
data.tofile("data.dat")
```

readdata.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy

data = numpy.fromfile("data.dat",dtype=numpy.float64)
print data
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm impressed with the time you put in to answering me. Your answer is full of good tips. I've applied then to my code and it is working a lot better now.